# How could I check if any of my HashSet values are more than my x?

Tags: c#, numbers, hashset

I'll use HS as my HashSet name.

For example:

```
int number1 = 5, number3 = 7;
HashSet<int> numbers;
numbers.Add(number1);
numbers.Add(number3);
if (numbers <= 10)
//do this and that...
```

Is there any way to do this with HashSets? If not what kind of other list type should I use and how would I use it for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`SortedSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd412070%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead which would be more efficient, it has a [`Min` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd411719(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
int number1 = 5, number3 = 7;
SortedSet<int> numbers= new SortedSet<int>();
numbers.Add(number1);
numbers.Add(number3);
if (numbers.Min <= 10) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 10;
bool containsValuesGreaterThenX = numbers.Where(n => n > x).Any();
```

Comment: `n` would be each number in your `HashSet` - read: for each number in the numbers check the following condition

Comment: But then I would have to manually write the number in the HashSet in?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, either you can use `Any` method to check if there is any number that greater than `10`:

```
bool result = numbers.Any(x => x > 10);
```

Or you can check if all numbers are less than `10`:

```
bool result = !numbers.All(x => x < 10);
```

Comment: @DarkDeSaint look into lambda expressions